# Wrist pain with UHG deadlifts and fat grip pullups

Tags: injury, wrist

About six months ago, I hurt my wrist whilst doing deadlifts with an underhanded grip (i.e. the position at the top of the deadlift looks like the bottom of a bicep curl). The pain was at the base of my wrist on the little finger side just above the round bony bit that sticks out.

I stopped doing the offending exercise and all was good.

Then today, whilst doing pullups on a tree branch (overhand grip) I experienced exactly the same injury. The tree branch was about the same circumference as a loaf of bread, and it is angled, so obviously it was very different to pull-ups using a pull up bar.

As soon as I felt the pain, I stopped and turned around (i.e. so the branch would be sloping in the opposite direction relative to my body), with the same result.

I've done plenty of pull-ups on that same tree before with no injury, so not sure why I hurt myself today.

Unloaded, my wrist feels 98%, no real pain and no loss of motion.

Any suggestions as to what might have happened? And what should I do? How long should I rest my wrist?

Comment: As always, seeing a doctor might not be the worst course of action. Other than that, did you warm up properly (tree pull ups don't sound like warm up to me)? Can you do the deadlift pain free with a lighter weight?

Comment: If you're using a sloping branch, there's the risk of your weight being pulled by one hand more than the other. Unless you can duplicate the problem, there's no way of identifying the cause other than **bad form,** **not warming up,** or simply **chance.** The cause might not even be related to the exercise itself; it could be prior activities. All we can give are **speculations** :).